A basis for compactly supported integrable functions
I am looking to construct a complete basis $f_n$ for all functions compactly supported on $[-1,1]$, that are integrable and continuous in $[-1,1]$ with the exception of possible singularities at $\pm 1$. For example,
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{1-x^2} & -1<x<1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{matrix}\right.$$
is the kind of function I'd like to be able to represent as a linear combination of the $f_n$.
I would also like the $f_n$ to grow smoother with increasing $n$. For example, $f_1$ and $f_2$ could be singular at $\pm 1$, $f_3$ and $f_4$ could be discontinuous at $\pm 1$, $f_5$ and $f_6$ could be $C^0$, etc. Basically I want $f_n$ to be $C^{O(n)}$.
The Paley–Wiener-Schwartz theorem suggests a way to construct such $f_n$: Take $\sin(k)/P_n(k)$ where $P_n(k)$ is an $n$th degree polynomial whose $n$ roots are also roots of $\sin(k)$, so $\sin(k)/P_n(k)$ is an entire function. For example at $n=1$ we might choose $P_1(k)=k$, and we just have $\sin(k)/P_1(k)=\text{sinc}(k)$. Then, let $f_n(x)$ be the Fourier transform of $\sin(k)/P_n(k)$.
This does produce a sequence of $f_n(x)$, all compactly supported on $[-1,1]$, and smoother with increasing $n$. My question is

Is this a complete basis?
There seems to be too many degrees of freedom in this construction of $f_n$: I can arbitrarily pick any $n$ roots of $\sin(k)$ to build $P_n(k)$.

